# Find maximum value of the first derivative

Tags: calculus

Let f is differentiable on $[0,1]$ and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.

Also we have that $|f''(x)| \leq A \quad \forall x \in (0,1)$.

Find the maximum value of $|f'(x)|$ on $[0,1]$.

I know standard method with finding second derivative in this case and so on but it works well for certain functions if I know it correctly.

I guess here we can use Taylor series $f(x) \approx f(a) + \frac{f'(a) \cdot (x-a)}{1!} + \frac{f''(a) \cdot (x-a)^2}{2!}$ but when we have some calculations with this expression I consider we have more and more error. I mean if we differentiate that approximation and then do it again we will be further from the answer to initial task because of approximation. And so the question is how to find maximum precisely. I know only two methods for finding maximums, first is using derivative, and second is bottom and top equal estimate. Are there other approaches for finding maximum? I will be very grateful for any help!

Comment: As long as you are careful, this can be shown by two applications of the fundamental theorem of calculus followed by the estimate $\left|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right| \leq \int_a^b |f(x)|\,dx$.  It gives an upper bound of $|f'(x)| \leq A/2$, after which you just have to look for a function that attains this maximum.

Comment: But why we consider, that if for certain function maximum = D for instance then for any f which satisfies all conditions above maximum = D? Maby we have function g which maximum value < D.

Comment: I don't follow your comment.  I've posted the answer I was talking about, so you can check it against your comment's concern.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x \in [0,1]$.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$f'(x) = f'(t) + \int_t^xf''(u)\,\mathrm{d}u.$$
By a second application of the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \int_0^1 f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}t \\ &= \int_0^1\left(f'(t) + \int_t^xf''(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right)\mathrm{d}t \\ &= f(1)-f(0)+\int_0^1\int_t^x f''(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}t \\ &= \int_0^1\int_t^x f''(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}t. 
\end{align*}$$

From here, we note that
$$|f'(x)| \leq \int_0^1\int_{\min(t,x)}^{\max(t,x)} |f''(u)|\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}t \leq \int_0^1\int_{\min(t,x)}^{\max(t,x)} A\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{A}{2}(x^2 + (1-x)^2) \leq \frac{A}2$$

---

From here, we look for a function $f$ such that $\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)| = A/2$.  At this moment, there's no guarantee that such a function exists, and perhaps it won't if our initial estimates are too weak, but we often can use those estimates to help our search.

Here, for instance, the first two inequalities actually become equalities if $f''(u) = A$ for every $u\in (0,1)$.  In that case, we can once again use the fundamental theorem of calculus a few times to find
$$f(x) = \frac{A}2(x^2-x)$$
for which $f'(1) = \frac{A}2$

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: But for the integrability of the function $f''(x)$ we need to know that $f''(x)$ is continuous, am I right?

Comment: @Angedon We don't need $f''$ to be continuous.  It suffices to have $f''$ Riemann integrable.  If you don't have that, we need to dip a little more into integration theory and use the Lebesgue integral, which gives the same conclusion (this uses both that $f'$ is differentiable everywhere and $f''$ is bounded to have the fundamental theorem of calculus apply in that context).